# Is it possible to use CFLDAP to retrieve all the users from a distribution group with only the group email address?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to use CFLDAP to retrieve all the users in a certain distribution group used by Exchange.  If this is possible, what do I use for the 'filter' attribute of CFLDAP?  Also, if all I have is the email address for the group (e.g. 'sales@example.com'), can I still get the user information, or do I need the name of the group that uses that email address?

For example, what would I put in the  block below?

```
<cfldap server = "foo.example.com"
        action = "query"
        name = "ldap2"
        start = "dc=foo,dc=example,dc=com"
        attributes = "givenName,sn,sAMAccountName,mail,employeeID,dn"
        filter="?????????????"
        username="BAR\eterps"
        password="12345" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Group name from the email address, I used Active Directory Explorer.  I'm sure there is a way to query for it as well.

Once I had the group name, I created my filter for CFLDAP: (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=Sales,ou=Email Distribution Groups,dc=foo,dc=example,dc=com))

So the resulting CFLDAP query looks like:

```
<cfldap server = "foo.example.com"
    action = "query"
    name = "ldap2"
    start = "dc=foo,dc=example,dc=com"
    attributes = "givenName,sn,sAMAccountName,mail,employeeID,dn"
    filter="(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=Sales,ou=Email Distribution Groups,dc=foo,dc=example,dc=com))"
    username="BAR\eterps"
    password="12345" >
```

Answer (score 0):

a filter is not required when using cfldap in my experience. What happens when you run the query without a filter?

Comment: If you run a query without a filter, won't it return everyone from the specified domain?  I just need a subset of users from a specified group, and I don't know how to express that in either a filter or query.  I've edited the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can modify the start attribute with the specific *Group dn*, and not just the *Root dn*, it should only return the info from that group.  If there is an attribute that points to users that are members of that group, make sure you include that in the attribute list.

If you dont modify the start attribute, your filter would be something like (`cn=groupname`) that points to the group you want.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get the groupname from the email address?

Comment: Try something like
(&(objectclass=group)(mail=sales@example.com))

You may have to change the objectclass attribute from group to what your group attribute would be.